# Initialize jQuery Object (Element) Before Placing it in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So, for a project I'm working on, I need to make users in a user selector sortable by network. The current way I am doing this is by creating the user:

```
clone += '<li class="'+ this.gender +'" data-id="'+ this._id +'">';
clone += '<img src="'+ this.image +'" />';
clone += '<span>'+ this.name +'</span>';
clone += '</li>';
```

Then having a jQuery object with the key being the network name and the value being an array of user ids, like:

```
{
  Network 1: [1,2,3,4]
  Network 2: [5,6,7,8]
}
```

Then, when a network is selected, I sort through all of li elements and match them against the array of ids and if it doesn't contain the id, hide the li element, like so:

```
for(var i = 0, n = education_ids[network].length;i < n;i++){
   $('.friends-list li[data-id='+ education_ids[network][i]+']').removeClass('chosen_network');
}
```

Unfortunately, it's really inefficient because basically for every iteration of the loop, the jQuery selector iterates over all the li elements, so if there are 1000 friends and 100 ids in the network, that's 100 1000 step iterations.

As a solution to this problem, I thought I might be able to add the jQuery objects to the array rather than the ids, so that way I could just iterate over them and add the classes (reducing the iterations 1000x). Here is how I'm currently trying to do that:

```
clone += '<li class="'+ this.gender +'" data-id="'+ this._id +'">';
clone += '<img src="'+ this.image +'" />';
clone += '<span>'+ this.name +'</span>';
clone += '</li>';

if(this.education){
    for(var i = 0, n = this.education.length; i < n ; i++){
    if(education[this.education[i].school.name]){
       education[this.education[i].school.name]++;
       education_ids[this.education[i].school.name].push($(clone));
    } else {
        education[this.education[i].school.name] = 1;
        education_ids[this.education[i].school.name] = [$(clone)];
    }
}
}
```

The relevant part is when I:

```
.push($(clone)
```

or initialize the array by doing:

```
[$(clone)]
```

Unfortunately, this technique doesn't work because at this point in my program, the elements actually haven't been added to the DOM. So, my question is as follows:

Is it possible to initialize these jQuery references BEFORE they are put into the DOM and if so, how would I do that?

And, if I can't do that, can you think of a more efficient way for me to solve this problem.

Just for reference, I am trying to make this faster because with the current strategy the looping freezes the DOM for anywhere between 1 and 2 seconds—not exactly the ideal experience for a user.

Thank you so much for any help you can give!

**EDIT: Progress made, but hitting an error!**

Ok, so I've made a little progress. Using the jQuery selector actually works, so now I'm doing:

```
    clone += '<li class="'+ this.gender +'" data-id="'+ this._id +'">';
    clone += '<img src="'+ this.image +'" />';
    clone += '<span>'+ this.name +'</span>';
    clone += '</li>';

    clone = $(clone)

    if(this.education){
        for(var i = 0, n = this.education.length; i < n ; i++){
            if(education[this.education[i].school.name]){
                education[this.education[i].school.name]++;
                education_ids[this.education[i].school.name].push(clone);
            } else {
                education[this.education[i].school.name] = 1;
                education_ids[this.education[i].school.name] = [clone];
            }
        }
    }

placeholder.push(clone);
```

And then after looping through all of the friends,

```
$('.friends-list').append(placeholder).fadeIn();
```

I think that should be working, but now I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Thoughts?

**EDIT: More progress, fixed the error, but sorting not working**

Ok, so I fixed the error by switching placeholder to an empty div like @Artimuz did, but now the sorting isn't working. So, basically I sort like this:

```
if("network is clicked and it was already selected") {
    for(var person in education_ids[network]){
        person.removeClass('chosen_network');
    }
} else //if it wasn't already selected {
     for(var person in education_ids[network]){
        person.addClass('chosen_network').removeClass('disabled');
}
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'addClass'
```

And so, once again I ask: thoughts?

Comment: I've just trying it in my chrome console : there is no problem to create a jquery object (`o = $('<div>').addClass('test')`), store it in an array (`a = [o]`), and then add it to the DOM (`$('body').append(a[0])`). So I think this is not the "revelant part".

Comment: On a basic example this work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/3xqx5/1/. Maybe can you share more of your code on jsfiddle ? I think we don't have enough data to solve this here.

Comment: And at which line is thrown the exception ?

Comment: Hey, so you actually helped with fixing the error, but it's still not working. I'll post relevant code in my question.

Comment: For the last edit : do a `for` with index (`for (i;i<count;i++)`). http://jsfiddle.net/3xqx5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I'll try to summarize some of your bugs here :

### For the first bug

No idea what was your problem. For me that worked.

[jsfiddle.net/3xqx5](http://jsfiddle.net/3xqx5)

### For the `NOT_FOUND_ERR` exception

It's just that you were trying to add a `array`, a pure javascript object, to the DOM. JQuery.append requires a jQuery object or a DOM element ! So you can put you items in a placeholder `<div>` or you iterate over your array and add items one by one.

[jsfiddle.net/3xqx5/1](http://jsfiddle.net/3xqx5/1)

### For the last error `Object 0 has no method 'addClass'`

The `for` statement you have done is not consistent, at least because it do a copy of each item at each iteration. Work directly on array elements by doing a `for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++)`

[jsfiddle.net/3xqx5/2](http://jsfiddle.net/3xqx5/2)

Answer (score 2):

The slowest part of any javascript is touching the DOM. Store your users:

```
var users = [
    {
        name : "dave",
        gender : "male",
        image : "omg.jpg"
    }
];
```

Store your networks (assuming you have less networks than users):

```
var networks = [
    [2,5,8]
];
```

Draw appropriately when required:

```
var html = "";
for(var i = networks[current].length; i--;){
    var id = networks[current][i];
    html += '<li class="'+ users[id].gender +'" data-id="'+ id +'">';
    html += '    <img src="'+ users[id].image +'" />';
    html += '    <span>'+ users[id].name +'</span>';
    html += '</li>';
}
$(container).html(html);
```

This way you iterate once over each user, the pure data which is the user. And you touch the DOM once to draw everything which is required.

This has the drawback of redrawing all the currently displayed users, but if that is an issue (if most people are in all of the networks for example) the solution can be modified to cache which users have already been drawn, and add the new users more discretely.

Comment: Okay, I think that will work, but it would involve redoing a lot of my code (which I will probably eventually do), so I want to see if there is another way. I'll mark as correct if (when) I eventually switch to your method! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't build HTML using string concatenation. That's horrible.

Comment: @Raynos Wow, thanks for showing me the light. I didn't realize I was being "horrible". Unfortunately it looks like [array.join is even "horribler"](http://jsperf.com/array-concat-vs-plus-equals/7)? Yes, I read your [September blog post about the evils of string concatenation](http://raynos.org/blog/22/The-DOM-ain't-a-string). Only it didn't contain any evils, did it? All rant and no reason. I see even you didn't suggest here that he use native constructors to build DOM fragments, so why did you go to the trouble of defacing my answer with your groundless ire?

Comment: Firstly string concatenation is bad because of "hello XSS injection". Secondly string concatenation it's ugly and hinders readability. Thirdly it encourages you to just build extra statements in and maintainability goes out of hand over time. Fourthly you didn't sanitize or HTML encode any entities in the strings you used. And of course using jQuery's html parser to build DOM is slower then using DOM methods directly. But wait! I already said all those in my blog post.

Comment: I would be interested to see your ground-breaking work on javscript based XSS. You see the operative work in XSS is SERVER. Are you worried that a user will input information which will be dynamically drawn on his screen so that he can spoof himself? Because I'm sure as hell hoping that you sanitize ALL data coming from a client before you store it on your side. XSS has two parts.One, a user passing dangerous information. Two, an unprotected server accepting them. How you write your javascript has NOTHING TO DO with XSS prevention.If it did, then firebug would hav been the end of the internet.

Comment: Yes, jQuery's html parser certainly is slower than using DOM methods directly. In fact, anything is slower than using DOM methods directly. The important thing here is, not by much. The purpose of string concatenation the way I used here is to provide a novice with a readable understandable answer which performs well enough. I reiterate that, not even YOU suggested he break open DOM methods to do this. Why? Because that would be a stupid thing to post in the jQuery section of SO.

Comment: @Sinetheta as a sidenote I would actually suggest you use DOM methods instead. Not to build document fragments when you can use a HTML templating system instead but one should manipulate the DOM with the DOM, not with jQuery. As for javascript based XSS attack vectors there are actually none that can be invoked (that I know of) in your particular snippet of code, but in general string concatenation opens one up to those attack vectors

Answer (score 1):

Building HTML using string concatenation is horrible, please avoid that.

As per @Sinetheta's data structure

```
var template = [
    "<li>",
        "<img></img>",
        "<span></span>",
    "</li>"
].join("");

var nodes = [];
for(var i = networks[current].length; i--;){
    var id = networks[current][i],
        user = users[id];

    var li = $(template);
    li.addClass(user.gender);
    li.data("id", id);

    var children = node.children();
    children.eq(0).prop("src", user.image);
    children.eq(1).text(user.name);

    nodes.push(li);
}

$.each(nodes, function (_, node) {
    $(container).append(node);
});
```

Comment: The one problem with this solution is that the last line: $(container).append(nodes); throws an error like the one in my question.

Comment: @JessePollak your right, jQuery doesn't work with arrays (which is just stupid)

Comment: Agreed. You can solve it the way you do it, or you can make nodes a div and append rather than push each li. I think that's probably the more efficient way, since that way you only have to loop through all the li's once.

Comment: @JessePollak the most efficient way is to make nodes a document fragment and append to it.